# Jquery if my div is empty

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I have this script here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($('.subhead').is(':empty')){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'none !important');
    }

});
</script>
```

What I am trying to do here is say if my class .subhead is empty then changed the background color, I have multiple .subhead div in code, if I run a script like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if($('.subhead').is(':empty')){
            alert('hi');
        }else{
            alert('hello');
        }
    });
    </script>
```

It will return Hello

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default setting of `background-colour` is `transparent`, not `none`. Try this:

```
if ($('.subhead').is(':empty')){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent !important');
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good catch... background:none; or background-color:transparent;

Answer (score 2):

Use `:empty` as selector, as you have several `.subhead` elements, using `is` doesn't do what you expect. Your code says that if all of the matched elements with class of `.subhead` are empty then set the `background-color` property of all the matched elements as `none`.

```
$('.subhead:empty').css('background-color', 'none !important');
```